# Let $A$ be a convex set in $\mathbb R^n $ , where $n>1$ ; then is it true that $\bar A \setminus A^{\circ}$ i.e. the boundary of $A$ is connected ?

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces, convex-analysis, connectedness

Let $A$ be a convex set in $\mathbb R^n $ , where $n>1$ ; then is it true that $\bar A \setminus A^{\circ}$ i.e. the boundary of $A$ is connected ? if yes , then is it also path connected ?

Comment: Wouldn't an infinitely long strip in $\Bbb R^2$ be a counter-example?

Comment: @GregoryGrant : You mean a "ray" in $\mathbb R^n$ ? But then the boundary is the "ray" itself , isn't it ?

Comment: I think if you add compact to convex then it might be true.

Comment: @GregoryGrant : But then what do you mean by "infinitely long strip" ?

Comment: No I mean $\{(x,y)\mid 0<x<1\}$.  Then the closure minus the interior is $\{(x,y)\mid x=0\}\cup\{(x,y)\mid x=1\}$.  Not connected.

Comment: @GregoryGrant : Uh huh , you are correct

Comment: @GregoryGrant : I wonder whether whole of compactness is needed or only boundedness is needed ..... and I checked your answer , I'll accept it

Comment: Good point, assuming compact is sufficient then boundedness would also have to be sufficient.

Comment: @GregoryGrant : I don't quite follow " assuming compact is sufficient then boundedness would also have to be sufficient " , I was thinking in geometric terms , why the strip didn't become connected , because in the closure we missed the above and below boundaries , that would not happen if we restrict it to be bounded before hand ....

Comment: Because if it were bounded then its closure would be compact, and I believe they would have to have the same boundaries if $A$ is convex.  So your weaker condition probably implies my stronger one, that's all I was saying.

Comment: @GregoryGrant : No , Thank You :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not true.  Let $A=\{(x,y)\mid 0<x<1\}$.  Then $A$ is convex and the closure of $A$ minus the interior of $A$ is $\{(x,y)\mid x=0\}\cup\{(x,y)\mid x=1\}$.  Not connected.  If you also require $A$ to be compact then I have a feeling it may be true.